# UPDATE  Syntax with ORDER BY, LIMIT and Multiple Tables 

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-update

Learning SQL, sorry if this is rudimentary. Trying to figure out a working `UPDATE` solution for the following pseudoish-code:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET tableA.col1 = '$var'
WHERE tableA.user_id = tableB.id
AND tableB.username = '$varName'
ORDER BY tableA.datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

The above is more like `SELECT` syntax, but am basically trying to update a single column value in the **latest row** of tableA, where a username found in tableB.username (represented by $varName) is linked to its ID number in tableB.id, which exists as the id in tableA.user_id.

Hopefully, that makes sense. I'm guessing some kind of `JOIN` is necessary, but subqueries seem troublesome for `UPDATE`. I understand `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are off limits when multiple tables are involved in UPDATE... But I need the functionality. Is there a way around this?

A little confused, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to nest ORDER BY and LIMIT in a FROM clause as part of a join. This let's you find the exact row to be updated (ta.id) first, then commit the update.

```
UPDATE tableA AS target
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ta.id
      FROM tableA AS ta
        INNER JOIN tableB AS tb ON tb.id = ta.user_id
        WHERE tb.username = '$varName'
        ORDER BY ta.datetime DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS source ON source.id = target.id
    SET col1 = '$var';
```

Hat tip to Baron Schwartz, a.k.a. Xaprb, for the excellent post on this exact topic:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/10/how-to-use-order-by-and-limit-on-multi-table-updates-in-mysql/

Comment: **Note:** This doesn't work for temporary tables - from the manual: `You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query syntax:

```
update work_to_do as target
   inner join (
      select w. client, work_unit
      from work_to_do as w
         inner join eligible_client as e on e.client = w.client
      where processor = 0
      order by priority desc
      limit 10
   ) as source on source.client = target.client
      and source.work_unit = target.work_unit
   set processor = @process_id;
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: This has been plagiarized from [Baron Schwartz (Xaprb)](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/10/how-to-use-order-by-and-limit-on-multi-table-updates-in-mysql/)