# Mysql update two columns from a sum of another table grouped by id

Tags: mysql

What I need is a sql for the following
I have tables

```
P which has columns PID, X, DX (PID is PK)
E which as columns EID, PID, X (EID is PK)
```

Table E has multiple entries for each PID

The statement which DOES NOT work was

```
update P,E set P.X=P.X+E.X, P.DX = E.X where P.PID = E.PID
```

I think it should be an update P set P.X = ?, P.DX = ? select( Sum(X) from E group by PID)

but I don't know how to take the output of the select and join it with P and set two values on each row;

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need a join in your update query, mysql supports a multi-table `UPDATE` as [Bill karvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) suggested [**mysql-syntax-for-join-update**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114534/mysql-syntax-for-join-update)

```
UPDATE P  JOIN E ON (P.PID = E.PID)
SET P.X=P.X+E.X, P.DX = E.X
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update P set P.X= (select sum(x) from E where e.pid=p.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

@dianuj's answer is right syntax.

But you have one to many relationship. so, one PID has 2+ values, It is not guarranteed which value is updated.

If you dot not concern this. @dianuj's query is OK. but, Just one value is allowed  for UPDATE. this question might help you. [UPDATE  Syntax with ORDER BY, LIMIT and Multiple Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544502/update-syntax-with-order-by-limit-and-multiple-tables)

Comment: Yes this is a many to one and it is important how this is updated.  Found this Update P, (select PID, sum(x) as x from E group by PID) as S set p.x = p.x + s.x, p.dx = s.x where p.PID = s.PID;